# wacom intous tablet map to multiple display

Tags: multiple-monitors, tablet, wacom

I recently installed ubuntu 19.10. My wacom tablet is suddenly mapped to only one of my 2 displays now. In the wacom tablet config tab I see the map to single display is off. When I click it on, I can then map the tablet to a specific display. But when I click it off, it automatically map to primary display. In 18.04 it was correctly map to both display I can move cursor between 2 displays. Is this a bug or is there any new settings I need to touch?

### update temporary workaround:

It seems to be a bug in ubuntu settings. The workaround is after each reboot I have to go to the setting switch to relative mapping then switch back to absolute mapping, then the tablet maps to entire screen 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, both when connecting via Bluetooth and via USB.
For now I've gone with relative positioning, which does allow me to reach both screens, but this is not ideal.

Comment: but relative position is not any option, it basically made the tablet useless

Comment: please check my update, I found a workaround.